# Swift : UITableViewCell Overlapping in debug view Hierarchy

Tags: ios, swift

[Cells Overlapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2bgoA.png)

I used custom class for UITableViewCell. It look fine
but the debug view Hierarchy cells is overlapping as image above.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(self.reuseIdentify, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ContactViewCell
    cell.lbContactName.text = self.dataSource[indexPath.row]

    return cell

}
```

Comment: can you please post some screenshot?

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/2bgoA.png

Answer (score -1):

Please check the custom UITableviewCell **Clip Subviews** property.

Comment: What is Clip Subviews property? can you make in more detail or post a sample come for us?

Comment: dear , vichhai :  clip subviews means there are some subviews inside the views .so if the sub view is having more dimension than the view then it may look like that view is hidden . in that case if u apply clip subviews to view ,then the inner view will not cross the view dimension,they will be clipped .

Comment: Dear sambo: I don't know how you are using the custom UITableViewCell.If you can give that custom class then i might be able to help .